# Calculating Probability over a long period of time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Four cities A, B, C & D are located as vertices of a square ABCD and are connected by roads that form the four sides of the square. *Mr. Walker travels thus*: if he is at city **i** in period **t**, then he randomly with probability 1/2 each, moves to one of the two vertices/cities that are adjacent to city **i** in period **t+1**.

If Mr. Walker is at **city A** in period **t=0**, then ***the respective probabilities with which he is at the cities A, B, C, D in period*** ***t=10*** are:

A) 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4

B) 0, 1/2, 0, 1/2

c) 1/2, 0, 0, 1/2

D) 1/2, 0, 1/2, 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He can only be at B or D on the odd values of t. So at t=10, he can only be on A or C, so the answer is D).

Comment: Could you explain the part why the probability would be 1/2? It's being calculated over a period of time. Shouldn't the value be some power of 1/2?

Comment: Say the probability was (1/2)^10 of land on A and C. He can't land on B or D so the probability of landing anywhere is 2*(1/2)^10. The probability of landing anywhere should be 1.

Comment: I understand your reasoning that he has moved 10 times so we should raise to a power of ten, but this is not a tree diagram. This is a loop

Comment: Would the method be any different if the probability of moving to one vertex was more than that of moving to the other adjacent vertex? Instead of being equal, i.e, 1/2 and 1/2?

Comment: Yes and it would be very complicated

Comment: I found another question along similar lines. it goes as follows: A monkey is sitting on a number line and in every time period t, moves to the right by 1 with a probability p and 1 unit to the left, with probability (1-p). p is anywhere between 1/2 &1. What is the probability that it reaches a positive integer k in some time period t>0? **Options are** :  a) p^k  b) 1  c) p^k/(1-p)^k  d) p/k   Also, using this, What is the probability that it reaches 0 in some t>0?

Comment: b)1. It's like flipping a coin infinitely. Eventually you'll get a million heads in a row.  So for both the probability is 1